# Outlook 2010 hung on updating outlook.com email account

Tags: email, sync, microsoft-outlook-2010, outlook.com

For the past week, through restarts of Outlook, and even a bounce of my machine, Outlook has been hung synchronizing my outlook.com account, after having moved messages from a different email inbox into the outlook.com inbox.

The old account *does not* have the moved message any more (those synched-out correctly).

The new account *does not* have the moved messages when acessing via the webui - ie, they are stuck in just Outlook.

My problem?

- I need to reimage this laptop for a friend
- I need Outlook to finish syncing all those messages out to the hosted email

How can I force this to happen?

Comment: Why don't you just let the sync job finish?

Comment: @Ramhound - it's been running for over a week, and has progressed no further than ~70%

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried opening Outlook in safe mode? From the "Run" dialogue, type one of the following:

`outlook /safe` – Starts Outlook without Microsoft Exchange Client Extensions (ECE), the Reading Pane, or toolbar customizations. Component Object Model (COM) add-ins are turned off.

`outlook /safe:1` – Starts Outlook with the Reading Pane off.

`outlook /safe:3` – Starts Outlook with Microsoft Exchange Client Extensions (ECE) turned off, but listed in the Add-In Manager. Component Object Model (COM) add-ins are turned off.

`outlook /safe:4` – Starts Outlook without loading outcmd.dat (customized toolbars).

If the messages are "stuck in just Outlook", then they should be in the *.PST file. Copy off that file and try opening it on another computer with Outlook to make sure. If so, then you can at least go ahead and re-image your friend's computer. Then install Outlook, open the PST file and try synching.

There's also a tool you can run to repair PST files called `scanpst.exe`. It's part of Outlook and you should be able to find a copy on the laptop.

Comment: I'm giving the scanpst a try currently - I'll let you know if this has helped :)

Comment: neither the scanpst, nor opening in safe mode seems to have helped :|

Answer (score -2):

Start with a new profile or, if possible, start up your sync on the new computer you're moving to.

Comment: Can you expand upon this with more detailed instructions?

Comment: How does one accomplish this exactly?

Comment: To create a new profile you can use Control Panel -> Mail -> Outlook -> Add Profile.